# how to get error message of failed ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to consume a webService which I get JSON Data from

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'JSON-P',
    //the url shows the correct JSON Data when I copy the URL in my browser
    url: 'http://url.com',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    },
       error: function(xhr, testStatus, error){console.log("Error occured: "+error+" "+xhr+" "+testStatus)}
})
```

In Firefox, It calls back with the error function, but I dont know what the problem is, it would be great to know the error message but my approach doesnt work.
thanks in advance

edit: In Chrome I get the following error:

> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

edit: It´s solved, the problem was indeed that json doesnt work cross site, and the data was not "jsonp-conform" (it had to set a function(json data...))arround the json data. This could be done by changing the url at the end "_&jsonp=successCallback. Sorry for bothering you

Comment: if you're doing a cross origin call you should use JSON-P instead

Comment: javascript is case sensitive . `type: 'GET',`

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: I updated the changes in my questions, however the ajax calls still back with the error function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there was a JSON object syntax error. Check your JSON object syntax error with [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error locally?

Try it on a server and if it doesn't work: [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: the webservice URL is on a remote server, but yes the error occurs in chrome when I load the file with the file:// protocol

Comment: @dan AJAX is relevant only when invoked from within a web page hosted on some sort of real server, not as raw file.